# Self-teaching Green's function approach to quantum many-body systems

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, many-body, greens-functions

My question is where can I find a good book, review, online course, or all of them for self-teaching [Green's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function) in quantum many-body problems (if it has problems with solutions for self-evaluating the concepts the better).

As I start to dig in the field, I find very nice books on one-particle green's function (e.g. [Economou's book](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=green%27s+function+economou&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Agreen%27s+function+economou&ajr=2)). However, the many-body non-equilibrium Green's function is presented always in a cloud of mysticism understandable only for people in field.

I am acquaintance with one particle Green's function at Sakurai's (scattering) level, but no more than that.

Comment: Providing a modern and very pedagogical exposition:
Nonequilibrium Many-Body Theory of Quantum Systems: A Modern Introduction by Gianluca Stefanucci and Robert van Leeuwen A recent and well written text on advanced condensed matter theory:
Introduction to Many-Body Physics by Piers Coleman

Answer (score 2):

There are many resources on many-body Green's functions (propagators) both on-line and in print. You may want to search "quantum field methods in many-particle systems" or "quantum field methods for condensed matter systems" or variations thereof.

In any case, I personally recommend the oldie-but-goodie book by Fetter and Walecka, Quantum Theory of Many-Particle Systems. It assumes a good footing in Quantum Theory and Statistical Mechanics, but otherwise covers everything you need for a good handle on the field's basic methods, starting with second quantization and up to finite-temperature and real-time Green's functions. It also includes problems. A Dover edition on Amazon sells for about $21 (new), but I found an on-line copy here:

[Fetter and Walecka, Quantum Theory of Many-Particle Systems](http://www.fulviofrisone.com/attachments/article/448/Fetter%20Walecka.pdf)

Other books available on-line, last one I didn't use directly, but all cover the basics in good detail:

[H.Kleinert, Path Integrals in Quantum Mechanics, Statistics, Polymer Physics, and Financial Markets](http://users.physik.fu-berlin.de/~kleinert/b6/psfiles/). Chap.2 covers the [Field Formulation of Many-Body Quantum Physics](http://users.physik.fu-berlin.de/~kleinert/b6/psfiles/Chapter-2-qftc3.pdf) pretty thoroughly, good intro.

Through the Mueller Group course site at Cornell, [Basic Training in Condensed Matter Physics/Many Body Field Theory](http://muellergroup.lassp.cornell.edu/Basic_Training_Spring_2013/Field_Theory.html) (unfortunately it seems it is no longer properly maintained since not all links check out anymore; listing only the two working ones for intro material):

[Brouwer, Theory of Many-Particle Systems](http://muellergroup.lassp.cornell.edu/Basic_Training_Spring_2013/Field_Theory_files/brouwer_notes.pdf)

[Nayak, Quantum Condensed Matter Physics](http://muellergroup.lassp.cornell.edu/Basic_Training_Spring_2013/Field_Theory_files/nayak_notes.pdf)

Also check their good list of in-print resources.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend Richard D. Mattuck *A Guide to Feynman Diagrams in the Many-Body Problem*. You can read some pages [here](https://books.google.com/books/about/A_Guide_to_Feynman_Diagrams_in_the_Many.html?id=pe-v8zfxE68C).

It's a very surface level introduction, but the first 3 or so chapters are presented at what he calls a "kindergarten" level so you shouldn't have any problems understanding it. However, the last part is most definitely *not* "kindergarten".